# Array PHP - Transforming

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I get some data from my database, with a query and then I loop it via a While loop:

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertisement_packages");  
while($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)):
echo $a['exposure]; //This prints out 1,2,3,4

endwhile;
```

How can I do, so exposure = 1 is exposure = 1 = Mini **and** exposure = 2 = Standard etc. etc.

Comment: What? Can you please formulate your question?

Comment: You want to print out 'exposure = 1', 'exposure = 2'?

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($a['exposure'] == 1){
    echo "Mini";
}
elseif($a['exposure'] == 2){
    echo "Standard";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$labels = array(1 => 'Mini', 2 => 'Standart');
echo $labels[$a['exposure']];
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to store the values independently instead of using a (possibly) enormous `if` structure:

```
$exposures = array(
    1    => 'Mini',
    2    => 'Standard',
    // and so forth
);

while($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)):
    echo $exposures[ $a['exposure'] ];
endwhile;
```

Just my $0.02 to make the code a bit more legible.

Answer (score 0):

**Another good way to do this is to maintain a table structure in the database that associates the exposure number to its description. This way you can display the exposure description straight from your database (you can also populate a drop-down menu on web forms from the exposure_info table). Just follow the example SQL to see if you understand. **

CREATE TABLE photo_clients(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  client_name VARCHAR(100),
  exposure TINYINT
);

CREATE TABLE exposure_info(
  exposure INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  description VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO exposure_info (description) VALUES ('mini'), ('standard'), ('poster');

INSERT INTO photo_clients (client_name, exposure) VALUES ('John Doe', 2), ('Jane Smith', 1), ('Johnny Walker', 3);

SELECT a.client_name AS client, b.description AS exposure FROM photo_clients a, exposure_info b WHERE a.exposure = b.exposure;

**The output of the above statement should look something like:**

```
client          exposure
------------------------
Jane Smith      mini
John Doe        standard
Johnny Walker   poster
```